# Valeurs du passé composé

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, passé-composé

> L'homme a toujours voulu posséder.
>
> J'arrive ; j'ai fini dans cinq minutes !

Dans les phrases ci-dessus, quelles valeurs exprime le passé composé ? Je sais que le passé composé présente un fait passé par raport au moment où l'on parle et considéré comme accompli, achevé. Il remplace par ailleurs le passé simple hormis l'écrit soutenu.

Je vois un futur très proche dans la deuxième phrase, mais c'est la première fois que j'ai rencontré cette tournure. La première phrase présente-elle une action passée ou toujours vraie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans la première phrase, le passé composé décrit un fait [habituel, intemporel](http://gabrielwyler.com/page102.html#Ach%C3%A8vementhabituel).

Dans la deuxième, il s'agit d'une [substitution du futur antérieur](http://gabrielwyler.com/page102.html#Tempssuppl%C3%A9antlefuturant%C3%A9rieur) que l'on rencontre dans la langue parlée. La forme soignée est :

> J'arrive; j'aurai fini dans cinq minutes.